# Where to find source code of Mozilla NoScript extension?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I read in wiki that NoScript is open source http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoScript, but on official site http://noscript.net/, I can't find any sources. So my question is: where to find sources? Or, is there something I did not understand, and the source code is not available?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The extension contains the source code - you just need to unzip it. See [Giorgio's response here](http://forums.informaction.com/viewtopic.php?p=9212#p9212).

> The whole source code is publicly available in every each XPI.
>
> You've got it on your hard disk right now, if you're a NoScript user, otheriwise you can download it here.
>
> You can examine and/or modify it by unzipping the XPI and the JAR inside, and "building" it back by rezipping both.
>
> It's been like that for ever, since the very first version.

Comment: Don't know much about .xpi. Thanks)

Answer (score 18):

The Firefox XPI format does not prevent you from simply extracting the contents of the plugin to examine the source code.

While I cannot find a canonical public repository, it looks like someone has systematically downloaded and extracted all the available XPIs and created a GitHub repository out of them.

https://github.com/avian2/noscript

If you'd like to do it yourself, XPI files are just standard ZIP files, so if you want to extract one yourself you can simply point an extraction program at it.

Here's an example of doing that from the command line:

```
mkdir noscript_source
cd noscript_source
curl -LO https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/downloads/file/219550/noscript_security_suite-2.6.6.8-fx+fn+sm.xpi
unzip noscript_security_suite-2.6.6.8-fx+fn+sm.xpi
```

That yields a directory structure that looks like this:

```
.
├── GPL.txt
├── META-INF
│   ├── manifest.mf
│   ├── zigbert.rsa
│   └── zigbert.sf
├── NoScript_License.txt
├── chrome
│   └── noscript.jar
├── chrome.manifest
├── components
│   └── noscriptService.js
├── defaults
│   └── preferences
│       └── noscript.js
├── install.rdf
├── mozilla.cfg
└── noscript_security_suite-2.6.6.8-fx+fn+sm.xpi
```

Then the main code is located inside `chrome/noscript.jar`. You can extract that to get at the JavaScript that makes up the bulk of the plugin:

```
cd chrome/
unzip noscript.jar
```

Which will yield the main source tree:

```
.
├── content
│   └── noscript
│       ├── ABE.g
│       ├── ABE.js
│       ├── ABELexer.js
│       ├── ABEParser.js
│       ├── ASPIdiocy.js
│       ├── ChannelReplacement.js
│       ├── ClearClickHandler.js
│       ├── ClearClickHandlerLegacy.js
│       ├── Cookie.js
│       ├── DNS.js
│       ├── DOM.js
│       ├── ExternalFilters.js
│       ├── FlashIdiocy.js
│       ├── HTTPS.js
│       ├── Lang.js
│       ├── NoScript_License.txt
│       ├── PlacesPrefs.js
│       ├── Plugins.js
│       ├── Policy.js
│       ├── Profiler.js
│       ├── Removal.js
│       ├── RequestWatchdog.js
│       ├── STS.js
│       ├── ScriptSurrogate.js
│       ├── Strings.js
│       ├── URIValidator.js
│       ├── about.xul
│       ├── antlr.js
│       ├── clearClick.js
│       ├── clearClick.xul
│       ├── frameOptErr.xhtml
│       ├── iaUI.js
│       ├── noscript.js
│       ├── noscript.xbl
│       ├── noscriptBM.js
│       ├── noscriptBMOverlay.xul
│       ├── noscriptOptions.js
│       ├── noscriptOptions.xul
│       ├── noscriptOverlay.js
│       ├── noscriptOverlay.xul
│       ├── options-mobile.xul
│       └── overlay-mobile.xul
├── locale
└── skin
```